# document.querySelector for main frame

Tags: chromium

I would like to retrieve a website's plain text in order to have it read by a computer voice to a blind user.

I believe that I need to select the main frame using

```
document.querySelector
```

to get this text.

However, I haven't been able to find out how to select the main frame.

How could I select the main frame?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this now:

```
Dim s As String
s = ""
s = s & "function GetAllText()"
s = s & "{"
s = s & " var body = document.body;"
s = s & " var textContent = body.innerText;"
s = s & "  return  textContent;"
s = s & "}"

Me.webkit1.AddCode s

Dim sRet$
sRet = Me.webkit1.Eval("GetAllText();")
```

This is for the WebKitX browser based on Chromium, but I guess it works similar to that on other browsers, too.